# Receiving Null check operator used on a null value error

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, syncfusion

I've been facing errors regarding my Syncfusion Calendar. Just recently, I was not able to initialize my _startDate and _endDate variables but some people suggested to make it nullable which I did but now it is giving me "Null check operator used on a null value" error.

Calendar Code:

```
class EventCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventCalendar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  EventCalendarState createState() => EventCalendarState();
}

List<Color> _colorCollection = <Color>[];
List<String> _colorNames = <String>[];
int _selectedColorIndex = 0;
late DataSource _events;
Meeting? _selectedAppointment;
DateTime? _startDate;
DateTime? _endDate;
late TimeOfDay _startTime;
late TimeOfDay _endTime;
bool _isAllDay = false;
String _subject = '';
String _notes = '';


class EventCalendarState extends State<EventCalendar> {
  EventCalendarState(); //check

  CalendarView _calendarView = CalendarView.month;
  late List<String> eventNameCollection;
  late List<Meeting> appointments;
  @override
  void initState() {
    _calendarView = CalendarView.month;
    appointments = getMeetingDetails();
    _events = DataSource(appointments);
    _selectedAppointment = null;
    _selectedColorIndex = 0;
    _subject = '';
    _notes = '';
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        drawer: UserDrawer(),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('Itinerary',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  color: Colors.black)),
        ),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
            child: getEventCalendar(_calendarView, _events)),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF003893),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push<Widget>(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (BuildContext context) => EventEditor()),
                )));
  }

  SfCalendar getEventCalendar(
    CalendarView _calendarView,
    CalendarDataSource _calendarDataSource,
  ) {
    return SfCalendar(
      view: _calendarView,
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      initialSelectedDate: DateTime.now(),
      todayHighlightColor: Color(0xFF003893),
      selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white60),
      showNavigationArrow: true,
      cellBorderColor: Colors.transparent,
      firstDayOfWeek: 1,
      allowedViews: [
        CalendarView.day,
        CalendarView.week,
        CalendarView.month,
        CalendarView.timelineWeek
      ],
      monthViewSettings: MonthViewSettings(
          showAgenda: true,
          agendaViewHeight: 250,
          appointmentDisplayMode: MonthAppointmentDisplayMode.appointment),
      dataSource: _calendarDataSource,
      initialDisplayDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, DateTime.now().month,
          DateTime.now().day, 0, 0, 0),
      timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
          minimumAppointmentDuration: const Duration(minutes: 60)),
    );
  }

  void onCalendarViewChange(String value) {
    if (value == 'Day') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.day;
    } else if (value == 'Week') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.week;
    } else if (value == 'Month') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.month;
    } else if (value == 'Timeline week') {
      _calendarView = CalendarView.timelineWeek;
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  List<Meeting> getMeetingDetails() {
    final List<Meeting> meetingCollection = <Meeting>[];
    eventNameCollection = <String>[];
    eventNameCollection.add('');

    _colorCollection = <Color>[];
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF3D4FB5));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF0F8644));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF8B1FA9));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFD20100));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFFC571D));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF85461E));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFFF00FF));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFFE47C73));
    _colorCollection.add(const Color(0xFF636363));

    _colorNames = <String>[];
    _colorNames.add('Blue');
    _colorNames.add('Green');
    _colorNames.add('Purple');
    _colorNames.add('Red');
    _colorNames.add('Orange');
    _colorNames.add('Caramel');
    _colorNames.add('Magenta');
    _colorNames.add('Peach');
    _colorNames.add('Gray');

    return meetingCollection;
  }
}

class DataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  DataSource(List<Meeting> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) => appointments![index].isAllDay;

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) => appointments![index].eventName;

  @override
  String getNotes(int index) => appointments![index].description;

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) => appointments![index].background;

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) => appointments![index].from;

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) => appointments![index].to;
}

class Meeting {
  Meeting(
      {required this.from,
      required this.to,
      this.background = Colors.green,
      this.isAllDay = false,
      this.eventName = '',
      this.description = ''});

  final String eventName;
  final DateTime from;
  final DateTime to;
  final Color background;
  final bool isAllDay;
  final String description;
}
```

Add/Edit/Delete Event in Calendar Code:

```
class EventEditorState extends State<EventEditor> {
  Widget _getAppointmentEditor(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 0, 0),
              title: TextFormField(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: _subject),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  _subject = value;
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Title',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 1.0,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              leading: Icon(
                Icons.subject,
                color: Colors.black87,
              ),
              title: TextField(
                controller: TextEditingController(text: _notes),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  _notes = value;
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 15,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Add description',
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 1.0,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 20, 2),
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('From', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 7,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                child: Text(
                                    DateFormat('EEE, MMM dd yyyy')
                                        .format(_startDate!),
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                onTap: () async {
                                  final DateTime? date = await showDatePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    initialDate: _startDate!,
                                    firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                                  );

                                  if (date != null && date != _startDate) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      final Duration difference =
                                          _endDate!.difference(_startDate!);
                                      _startDate = DateTime(
                                          date.year,
                                          date.month,
                                          date.day,
                                          _startTime.hour,
                                          _startTime.minute,
                                          0);
                                      _endDate = _startDate!.add(difference);
                                      _endTime = TimeOfDay(
                                          hour: _endDate!.hour,
                                          minute: _endDate!.minute);
                                    });
                                  }
                                }),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: _isAllDay
                                  ? const Text('')
                                  : GestureDetector(
                                      child: Text(
                                        DateFormat('hh:mm a')
                                            .format(_startDate!),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        final TimeOfDay? time =
                                            await showTimePicker(
                                                context: context,
                                                initialTime: TimeOfDay(
                                                    hour: _startTime.hour,
                                                    minute: _startTime.minute));

                                        if (time != null &&
                                            time != _startTime) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _startTime = time;
                                            final Duration difference =
                                                _endDate!
                                                    .difference(_startDate!);
                                            _startDate = DateTime(
                                                _startDate!.year,
                                                _startDate!.month,
                                                _startDate!.day,
                                                _startTime.hour,
                                                _startTime.minute,
                                                0);
                                            _endDate =
                                                _startDate!.add(difference);
                                            _endTime = TimeOfDay(
                                                hour: _endDate!.hour,
                                                minute: _endDate!.minute);
                                          });
                                        }
                                      })),
                        ]),
                  ],
                )),
            ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 20, 2),
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('To', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                    SizedBox(height: 5),
                    Row(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 7,
                            child: GestureDetector(
                                child: Text(
                                  DateFormat('EEE, MMM dd yyyy')
                                      .format(_endDate!),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                ),
                                onTap: () async {
                                  final DateTime? date = await showDatePicker(
                                    context: context,
                                    initialDate: _endDate!,
                                    firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                                    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
                                  );

                                  if (date != null && date != _endDate) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      final Duration difference =
                                          _endDate!.difference(_startDate!);
                                      _endDate = DateTime(
                                          date.year,
                                          date.month,
                                          date.day,
                                          _endTime.hour,
                                          _endTime.minute,
                                          0);
                                      if (_endDate!.isBefore(_startDate!)) {
                                        _startDate =
                                            _endDate!.subtract(difference);
                                        _startTime = TimeOfDay(
                                            hour: _startDate!.hour,
                                            minute: _startDate!.minute);
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }
                                }),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                              flex: 3,
                              child: _isAllDay
                                  ? const Text('')
                                  : GestureDetector(
                                      child: Text(
                                        DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(_endDate!),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () async {
                                        final TimeOfDay? time =
                                            await showTimePicker(
                                                context: context,
                                                initialTime: TimeOfDay(
                                                    hour: _endTime.hour,
                                                    minute: _endTime.minute));

                                        if (time != null && time != _endTime) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _endTime = time;
                                            final Duration difference =
                                                _endDate!
                                                    .difference(_startDate!);
                                            _endDate = DateTime(
                                                _endDate!.year,
                                                _endDate!.month,
                                                _endDate!.day,
                                                _endTime.hour,
                                                _endTime.minute,
                                                0);
                                            if (_endDate!
                                                .isBefore(_startDate!)) {
                                              _startDate = _endDate!
                                                  .subtract(difference);
                                              _startTime = TimeOfDay(
                                                  hour: _startDate!.hour,
                                                  minute: _startDate!.minute);
                                            }
                                          });
                                        }
                                      })),
                        ]),
                  ],
                )),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            ListTile(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 20, 2),
                leading: Icon(
                  Icons.access_time,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
                title: Row(children: <Widget>[
                  const Expanded(
                    child: Text('All-day'),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                      child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Switch(
                            value: _isAllDay,
                            onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _isAllDay = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ))),
                ])),
            const Divider(
              height: 1.0,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
            ListTile(
              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 20, 2),
              leading: Icon(Icons.lens,
                  color: _colorCollection[_selectedColorIndex]),
              title: Text(
                _colorNames[_selectedColorIndex],
              ),
              onTap: () {
                showDialog<Widget>(
                  context: context,
                  barrierDismissible: true,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return _ColorPicker();
                  },
                ).then((dynamic value) => setState(() {}));
              },
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 1.0,
              thickness: 1,
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(getTile()),
              backgroundColor: _colorCollection[_selectedColorIndex],
              leading: IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.close,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      Icons.done,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      final List<Meeting> meetings = <Meeting>[];
                      if (_selectedAppointment != null) {
                        _events.appointments!.removeAt(_events.appointments!
                            .indexOf(_selectedAppointment));
                        _events.notifyListeners(CalendarDataSourceAction.remove,
                            <Meeting>[]..add(_selectedAppointment!));
                      }
                      meetings.add(Meeting(
                        from: _startDate!,
                        to: _endDate!,
                        background: _colorCollection[_selectedColorIndex],
                        description: _notes,
                        isAllDay: _isAllDay,
                        eventName: _subject == '' ? '(No Title)' : _subject,
                      ));

                      _events.appointments!.add(meetings[0]);

                      _events.notifyListeners(
                          CalendarDataSourceAction.add, meetings);
                      _selectedAppointment = null;
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    })
              ],
            ),
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 5, 5, 5),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[_getAppointmentEditor(context)],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButton: _selectedAppointment == null
                ? const Text('')
                : FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (_selectedAppointment != null) {
                        _events.appointments!.removeAt(_events.appointments!
                            .indexOf(_selectedAppointment));
                        _events.notifyListeners(CalendarDataSourceAction.remove,
                            <Meeting>[]..add(_selectedAppointment!));
                        _selectedAppointment = null;
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      }
                    },
                    child:
                        const Icon(Icons.delete_outline, color: Colors.white),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  )));
  }

  String getTile() {
    return _subject.isEmpty ? 'New event' : 'Event details';
  }
}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: On which line are you getting these errors for the first time?

Comment: run the code in vs code using 'start debugging' options, and it will get you to the exact variable location which is causing null check operator error and let us know where the execution stop

Comment: It stops at ```Text(DateFormat('EEE, MMM dd yyyy').format(_startDate!),``` for the ListTile where user selects "From" date in class EventEditorState.